# Is Euclidean TSP strongly NP-hard

Tags: np-complete, traveling-salesman

Is Euclidean TSP strongly NP-hard? What I mean is if it is NP-hard with weights specified in unary?

Can someone provide a reference?

Comment: Weights are distances in Euclidean TSP, so I assume you mean that the *coordinates* are specified in unary.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Yes, indeed! (Though I hadn't thought of it this way before). Is it still NP-hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Papadimitriou in his "The Euclidean Traveling Salesman Problem Is NP-complete" paper reduces from Exact Cover to Euclidean TSP.

All the coordinates of the points are of polynomial magnitude.

And the required precision for the $L_0$ value in page 243 is to be able to distinguish between $a$ and ${(a^2+1)}^\frac12$. And near the end of page 241, he wrote "An adequate value of $a$ is 20." So the required precision is finite. Since you only have $n(4a + 13 + 2^\frac12)$, that would only magnify the difference.

All the page numbers above are in the proceedings containing his paper and can be seen once you have downloaded the paper.